# Display button in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How to display the `button` in front of the string where the pointer is set?

[image: Example]

At the moment, the button appears opposite the string where the click occurred.

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    button2.Visible = true;

    int index = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
    int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index);
    button2.Visible = true;
    int x = richTextBox1.Location.X - 10;
    int y = 25;

    for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        button2.Location = new Point(280, Cursor.Position.Y - 170);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wan to display button "inside" of richTextBox1

```
    private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);

        if (pos.X > button2.Width + 4)
        {
            if (button2.Parent != richTextBox1)
            {
                button2.Parent.Controls.Remove(button2);
                richTextBox1.Controls.Add(button2);
            }
            button2.Location = new Point(pos.X - button2.Width - 2, pos.Y);
        }
        else
        {
            if (button2.Parent == richTextBox1)
            {
                button2.Parent.Controls.Remove(button2);
                richTextBox1.Parent.Controls.Add(button2);
            }
            button2.Location = new Point(richTextBox1.Left - button2.Width - 2, pos.Y + richTextBox1.Top);
        }
    }
```

If you wan to display button at the line start:

```
    private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
        button2.Location = new Point(richTextBox1.Left - button2.Width - 2, pos.Y + richTextBox1.Top);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, can you send me an example of the project?

Answer (score 1):

You can get caret position using [`RichTextBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getpositionfromcharindex(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
int index = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
Point caretPosition = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(index);
```

then you can use it to change button's location:

```
int x = 280; //maybe something like richTextBox1.Location.X - 10;
int y = caretPosition.Y; //you might need to adjust this to button's point of reference
button2.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Handle [`RichTextBox.SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event if you want to relocate the button when caret moves and not on a mouse click.